# Oracle Sql selecting all data from a list of views

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to write a sql to select all data from a list of views for a particular view.

I'm getting all the user view this way:

```
select view_name from user_views
```

Say the output is:

```
emp_v
dept_v
countries_v
jobs_v
```

Is it possible for me to pass one of these views as parameter in the original sql(which is pulling all the views) so i can get all the data in this view?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're looking for. Are you trying to query ALL the views and then only get the fields for one of them? Or are you looking to query only one of the views and have results returned? Please edit your question (the edit button is immediately beneath the tags) and add some clarification as to what you're looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for.  This will loop those views and select everything in them.  **NOTE:** This can cause a lot of DBMS_OUTPUT.  I suggest hardcoding the cursor for a specific view first to make sure it is what you are looking for.

(1) Create this procedure...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure print_view(p_query in varchar2) is

    l_theCursor     integer default dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    l_columnValue   varchar2(4000);
    l_status        integer;
    l_descTbl       dbms_sql.desc_tab;
    l_rowCnt        number := 0;
    l_colCnt        number;

begin

    dbms_sql.parse(l_theCursor, p_query, dbms_sql.native);
    dbms_sql.describe_columns(l_theCursor, l_colCnt, l_descTbl);

    dbms_output.put_line(l_colCnt);

    for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
        dbms_sql.define_column(l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue, 4000);
    end loop;

    l_status := dbms_sql.execute(l_theCursor);

    while(dbms_sql.fetch_rows(l_theCursor) > 0) loop
        l_rowCnt := l_rowCnt +1;
        dbms_output.put_line('========== ROW '||l_rowCnt||' ==========');
        for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
            dbms_sql.column_value(l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue);
            dbms_output.put_line(rpad(l_descTbl(i).col_name, 30)||': '||substr(l_columnValue, 1, 200));
        end loop;
    end loop;

end print_view;
/
```

(2) Then run this...

```
declare

/*
NOTE: Edit the where clause. You should try this with just a single view first to make sure this is what you want.
*/
cursor cursor1 is
select view_name from user_views
where view_name in ('emp_v','dept_v','countries_v','jobs_v');

begin
    for c1 in cursor1 loop
        print_view('select * from '|| c1.view_name); /* Pass the view as a parameter like requested. */
    end loop;
end;
/
```